# Do package installed with pip change according to python configuration?

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have a conceptual doubt regarding how Python packages dependencies are installed/configured, this is related to compilation configurations.

**Case 1**

Installed packages `pyscreenshot, image, pillow` using pip from a python 2.7 configured with `ucs2` in the user lib space (--user). Executed some api to get desktop screenshot, everything runs smoothly.

**Case 2**

Executed another python 2.7 configured with `ucs4`, it finds the packages due that those were installed in the user space. Executed same api to get desktop screenshot, it crashes. The ucs4 configuration was incompatible with how the packages works.

So why that happened? could different versions of the same packages be installed depending on how Python was configured?

Note:
ucs2/ucs4 explanation https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why that happened?

It happened because when both C (binary) codes were loaded into memory, each one of them treated strings in different ways. In [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html) it is clearly stated that: "... UCS2 and UCS4 Python builds are not binary compatible. Please keep this in mind when writing extensions or interfaces."

Documentation also says that: "Python’s **default builds use a 16-bit** type for Py_UNICODE and store Unicode values internally as UCS2." So what you did was to: install a package compatible with the default interpreter and run it with a non compatible Python interpreter.

> could different versions of the same packages be installed depending on how Python was configured?

I am not sure if pip is able to handle UCS2 and UCS4 package variants. What happens when you install the same packages using the pip from your UCS4 interpreter? If the UCS2 version of the package is installed when using the UCS4 version of pip, I would recommend to download the source distribution of the package and compile it yourself with UCS4.

I know that pip can differentiate between os (windows / linux) and ABI, but I don't think it can handle UCS differences.

Comment: Wide unicode is marked with `u` ABI flag in wheel name, e.g. `pkg-1.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl` was built with wide unicode support, and `pkg-1.0-cp27-cp27m-linux_x86_64.whl` wasn't. Depending on whether the underlying Python dist was built with or without wide unicode support, `pip` will select the appropriate wheel. Source dists are built to wheels first, then installed, so the same logic applies to them, although the ABI flags in source dist case are always correct (the target Python installation is also used for building wheels).